# Is there another way of obtaining boolean values from a method than return?

Tags: java, methods, scope, boolean

I´m doing a World of Zuul based game for my programming course. There is a method called createRooms(), that creates HashMap objects of Room class and calls a setExits() method that passes a String and Room arguments which sets the exit for each room in the game. e.g.

```
private void createRooms()
{
    garage = new Room("garage description");

    garage.setExit("inside", livingroom);
    garage.setExit("outside", outsideHouse);
}
```

I want to restrict access to the outside Exit, and i thought of using an if statement to do so:

```
    garage = new Room("garage description");
    boolean garageDoorOpen = false;

    garage.setExit("inside", livingroom);
    if (garageDoorOpen != false) 
    {
    garage.setExit("outside", outsideHouse);
    }
```

However I am having problems changing the value of the garageDoorOpen boolean. I want to be able to do it from another method, but that methods return boolean is reserved for another purpose.

I realise this might be a very roundabout way of doing this but honestly it's the only solution i've been able to come up with so far.

Comment: your garageDoorOpen can be class level.

Comment: setExit() takes two parameters, it could take three. It's a bit hard to answer without a model. What is sure is that your garageDoorOpen variable is local and will be destroyed at the end of the function.

Comment: Thank you for your help!